# Query for addition of values in the column and insert it into another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

[Click here to find the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsQn4.jpg)

1. I have written a query for addition of all totalindent for particular pointname.
2. Here the problem is how to insert the total indent value of tbl1 to tbl2 using pointname tbl2 as a constraint.
3. The query is

   SELECT pointname,SUM(Totalindent) FROM paperagents_tbl GROUP BY pointname ASC;

Comment: The above query output is YNT 2500  BEL 1500

Comment: It's considered very rude here to post images of your data rather than using a `<pre>` block with the text.

Comment: sure i will do it from the next time

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query to get your desired output -

Here I have taken two tables i.e. **tbl1** and **tbl2**.

```
INSERT into tbl2 (pointname, circulation) SELECT pointname, SUM(Totalindent) FROM tbl1 GROUP BY pointname ASC
```

Comment: I have data already pointname in tbl2 need to insert the Totalindent

Comment: From the above query, you will get the **pointname** and **circulation** in your second table which are the total of first table. You need anything else ?

Comment: ya but the query should be like this i need to insert only totalindent to be inserted in the circulation according to pointname present in the tbl2